# QSharedMemory, signals and QBuffer

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to get signals when a `QSharedMemory` is written to. I tried it a few times in the folowing way:

```
QSharedMemory *sm = new QSharedMemory("key", this);
QByteArray *ba;
QBuffer *buff;
if(sm->create(1024))
{
    ba = new QByteArray();
    ba->setRawData((char*)sm->data(), sm->size());
    buff = new QBuffer(ba, this);
    connect(buff, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(bufferReadyRead()));

    memset(sm->data(), NULL, sm->size());
    QByteArray response = myDomDoc.toByteArray();

    sm->lock();
    buff->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    memcpy((char*)sm->data(), response.data(), sm->size()-1);
    buff->close();
    /****Here I want the QBuffer's readyRead() signal to emit ****/
    sm->unlock();
}
```

My attempt might be a little contorted but I hope you get the idea. I am trying to wrap a `QBuffer` around a `QSharedMemory` data so that I can get a signal when somebody writes to the `QSharedMemory`.

Is this a good way to do this? Is there a better way to do it? If not what is best way to get a signal when my `QSharedMemory` is written to.

I think the problem is that as soon as I write to the shared memory data the QByteArray implements a copy-on-write and therefore the `QBuffer` does not detect something written to its data.

Am I right?

Best regards.

Comment: This will not work. `QBuffer` is only a wrapper around `QByteArray`. It doesn't track outside changes of underlying byte array. It emits `readyRead` signal only when the buffer itself is changed somewhere else.

Comment: From the QtDocumentation I can see what led you to believe that QBuffer and QSharedMemory might work to in a kind of [IPC way](http://blog.coherent-labs.com/2012/08/building-shared-memory-ipc.html). My hunch is that QIODevice only intended to emit readyRead for things like sockets/pipes/local-sockets- for when new data is appended not when it's modified.  If you're working with multiple threads and such you may be able to synchronize/notify using conditional variables.  Another possibility includes sending a small notification (using local sockets or even UDP) about the update to shared memory

Comment: Thanks everyone. Guess I have to abandon this way of doing this.